# How to activate BIM 360 design collaboration service with Forge?

Tags: autodesk-forge

After creating a new BIM 360 project with Forge, we're trying to activate the Design Collaboration service through the BIM 360 API. We found how to activate a service [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/account-admin/activate-service/), but the service types referenced [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/overview/parameters/#service-type) do not include Design Collaboration. Is there a way to [POST](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-users-POST/) a project admin for the Design Collaboration service and thereby activate it, or another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the Design Collaboration service is not exposed in the "service_type" yet, you can not activate this service with the API currently.